# How to decorate the margins of a Bootstrap grid layout with row alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The page has a simple two-column Bootstrap layout:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      column 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap renders the columns in the center of the window with equal-sized left and right margins.

```
:       | column 1    | column 2    |        :
```

The requirement is to decorate the margins (the regions between the vertical bar and the colon). Decorations are determined by -- and aligned with -- row content. Decorations are non-essential elements that the responsive layout may clip or eliminate on small-screen devices. This last bit is challenging me.

At first I thought of adding more columns, or embedding the container within another container and placing decorations in the outer container. But (of course) Bootstrap treats the "decoration" columns as essential content. When screen real-estate becomes scarce, the decorations occupy valuable space.

Is it possible to tell Bootstrap that a column is non-essential, decorative, only to be displayed as space allows?

***EDIT***

Ahmad Dalao asked for a screenshot. I've cobbled something together with the caveat that I am asking the question because I don't know how to get this working.

The image below is a rendering of two nested containers. The parent container is home to the left and right margins; these are the non-essential, decorative columns. The child container is home to the content columns.

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background:white;margin:0;padding:0;">
  <div class="row"  style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:right;border: 1px solid blue;margin:0;padding:0;">
       <img src="decoration-left-margin.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8"   style="border: 1px solid blue;margin:0;padding:0;">
      <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid green;margin:0;padding:0;">
        <div class="row"  style="margin:0;padding:0;">
          <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align:left;border: 1px solid orange;margin:0;padding:0;">
            <img src="decoration-left-content.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align:right;border: 1px solid orange;margin:0;padding:0;">
            <img src="decoration-right-content.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:left;border: 1px solid blue;margin:0;padding:0;">
       <img src="decoration-right-margin.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the desired output. Thank you.

Comment: See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you put `.col-sm` on the essential columns but didn't mention how much space you want the decorative columns to take up.

If I assume the decorative columns would take up the same amount of spaces the essential columns would do, then the following structure should give you what you want:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="decorative col-sm d-sm-block d-none"></div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            column 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            column 2
        </div>
        <div class="decorative col-sm d-sm-block d-none"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Those 2 decorative columns won't take up any space until small break point and up.

[image]

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/4j1u7q0f/16/

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! One minor extra detail is that the decorative images need to be added to the css `background` of the margin columns. This construction allows the decorations to be clipped when the window doesn't have space to display them entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I approached it differently. See https://codepen.io/Mikeritteronline/pen/YzqLVmm

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col align-self-center d-none d-md-block text-right p-0">
      <img src="//placehold.it/240x48" class="pull-right" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis sequi suscipit quas nisi quae impedit hic iure aperiam eligendi, nam, nesciunt quaerat dolor ipsam amet temporibus provident, eius architecto soluta?</div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum cumque veritatis eaque eius sed libero deleniti et, dignissimos ipsum. Qui quis doloremque illum saepe aspernatur autem tempora cum, reprehenderit consequatur!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla voluptates culpa voluptatem nobis sapiente ipsum corrupti delectus, consequatur quia temporibus dolore modi quasi libero dicta ratione nostrum soluta. Obcaecati, molestias.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-center d-none d-md-block text-left p-0">
      <img src="//placehold.it/240x48" class="pull-left" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS is

```
.pull-right{
  margin-right: -2rem;
}
.pull-left{
  margin-left: -2rem;
}
```

I hid the decorative columns up to medium breakpoint. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Then used negative margins to pull in the images. Bootstrap doesn't have a builtin utility.

I used `align-self-center` to center the decorator columns vertically. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment